# Expectation of function including indicator function

Tags: probability, expected-value

When I watched UCB proof, I saw the following equality: 
$$\sum_{t=1}^T E[x\cdot\mathbb{I}[x>a]] =  \int_a^{+\infty} \sum_{t=1}^T P(x>y) dy$$ 
I want to know how to prove the above equality in detail.

Comment: Where is your confusion? The indicator is 1 when $x > a$ so it suffices to integrate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the confusion lies in using a lower-case literal for a random variable.  Let's use capital $X$ rather than lower case $x$

Now, if $a>0$ and $X$ has probability density function $f_X$, then:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{t=1}^T \mathsf E[X\cdot\mathbb{I}[X>a]] &= \sum_{t=1}^T ~\mathsf E[X\cdot\Bbb I[X>a]]\\[1ex]&=\sum_{t=1}^T~\int_\Bbb R s\cdot\Bbb I[s>a]~f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s\\[1ex]&=\sum_{t=1}^T~\int_a^\infty s~f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s\\[1ex]&=\sum_{t=1}^T~\int_a^\infty \int_0^s f_X(s)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm ds\\&=\sum_{t=1}^T~\int_a^\infty\int_y^\infty f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\sum_{t=1}^T~\int_a^\infty \mathsf P(X>y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=  \int_a^{\infty} \sum_{t=1}^T P(X>y)\,\mathrm dy\end{align}$$